# printing out items in a dynamic array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print out items that are stored in a vector that contains a instance of a class for example:

```
vector<Tree *> vec_;
```

I understand that in order to insert a item into the vector I can dynamically allocate memory to insert a Tree object into the vector for example:

Method 1:

```
Tree * obj = new Tree();
vec_.push_back(obj);
```

Method 2:

```
vec_.push_back(new Tree());
```

First off I want know how to delete dynamically allocated memory for Method 2 because I understand that for Method 1, I would do something like:

```
delete obj;
```

Lastly I'm having trouble printing out the items in our vector, I am getting a error stating that there is invalid operands to binary expression (I'm not sure what this means) This is what I've tried:

```
vec_.push_back(obj); //this is just to show that the vector is populated. (pseudo)
vec_.push_back(obj1);
vec_.push_back(obj2);
vec_.push_back(obj3);
for(int i = 0; i < vec_.size();i++)
    cout << *(vec_[i]) << endl;
```

Comment: If you allocate it and stick it in a list that doesn't mean you're off the hook from de-allocating it later. You'll have to spin through that list and `delete` each item.

Comment: Your printing will work only if your Tree class has operator << returning a string implemented.

Comment: You should print the value inside tree like , cout << *(vec_[i]).id << endl; For delete use delete vec_[i];

Comment: This is a case where using a proper iterator would be less messy than a regular old `for`.

Comment: @lobo what does .id signify?

Comment: you should replace id with some attribute of your tree, if your tree struct has a variable say data , you should replace id with data. Print the variable where you are storing your data.

Comment: @lobo I've tried that method and it does not work, the compiler is saying "indirection required pointer operand"

Comment: use '->' instead of '.' , I forgot that it is a pointer

Comment: @lobo believe me when I say that Ive tried, is this an issue where I need to overload the << operator?

Comment: Post your tree definition, if you have single value attribute, overriding can be skipped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108461/discussion-between-bthegreatest-and-lobo).

Answer (score 0):

delete dynamically allocated memory for Method 2:

```
Tree *obj = vec_.back();
vec_.pop_back();
delete obj;
obj = NULL;
```

Comment: is there a more efficient method? In regards to execution time

Comment: @Bthegreatest - more efficient in terms of what? Execution time or lines of source-code or perhaps executable size. Maybe something else entirely!?

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that in order to insert a item into the vector I will
>   need to dynamically allocate memory

Your understanding is incorrect. In the example you showed, your vector contains pointers to `Tree` objects. You are not required to dynamically allocate the `Tree` objects, just so they can be inserted into the vector. You can insert any pointer to a `Tree` object into your vector. It could certainly be allocated, but it doesn't have to be:

```
Tree obj;

vec_.push_back(&obj);
```

Now, there may be other reasons why you wouldn't want to do this, this is true.

You can push the same object into the vector more than once:

```
Tree *obj=new Tree();

vec_.push_back(obj);
vec_.push_back(obj);
```

All that `vec_` is, is a vector of pointers to `Tree`s. That's it. Nothing more. Nothing else. Where those pointers come from, your `vec_` doesn't care. It's none of its business.

Now, going back to the topic of deleting your `Tree`s. The first thing you need to understand that if you still have the original `obj` pointer, then just because you did a

```
delete obj;
```

That doesn't mean that the pointer to the same object, in your `vec_` magically disappeared. It's going to still be there. And if you attempt to use it and dereference it, undefined behavior results, which is usually a crash. Welcome to C++.

Now, perhaps after you reread the above paragraph a few times, you might be able to figure out the answer to your last question, how to deallocate the object if you didn't use the temporary `obj` pointer, before it got pushed back into the `vec_` array.

It is true that you have to delete the object that you have allocated, but you don't need the original pointer for it. For example, your so-called "Method 1" could be:

```
Tree *obj=new Tree();

vec_.push_back(obj);

delete vec_.back();   // Instead of delete obj;
vec_.pop_back();
```

You pushed the pointer to the object at the back of your vector. To delete it, you take the pointer at the back of your vector, which is the same object you've allocated, and you delete it. And, to make sure that your vector does not contain an invalid pointer anymore, to a deleted object, you `pop_back()` it.

So, what would you do for your so-called "Method 2"?. Would you believe exactly the same thing?

```
vec_.push_back(new Tree());

delete vec_.back();
vec_.pop_back();
```